# Странное поведение PHP при подключении к HTTPS

Tags: php, ssl, https

Ситуация:

1. Есть сайт провайдера, на котором есть панель управления с возможностью доступа через API. Доступ ко всему этому хозяйству идёт через HTTPS-протокол. Конкретный адрес точки входа: `https://server158.hosting.reg.ru:1500/ispmgr`
2. Есть скрипт на PHP, который должен обращаться по API к этой панели управления;
3. *(возможно это важно)* Скрипт работает на локальном компьютере в виртуальной машине на Linux. Запускается как консольное приложение;
4. При попытке обращения через скрипт стабильно имеем ошибку

   `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`
5. При попытке обращения через CURL из командной строки той же виртуальной машины и через отладчик REST-запросов (с этого же компьютера, но работающий вне виртуальной машины) всё работает без проблем.

Лечил ли кто что-то подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Провёл собственные поиски причины проблемы. Оказалось, что она в изначальной ненастроенности путей к корневым сертификатам в конфигах PHP.

Особо замечу, что это будет полезно всем, кто, как и я, использует виртуальную машину Laravel Homestead.

Лечится всё это прописыванием следующей опции в `php.ini`:

```
[openssl]
;...
openssl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Если также вы используете cURL, в конфиги стоит также добавить ещё одну строку:

```
[curl]
;...
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто вы забыли добавить конфигурацию которая проверяет/игнорирует сертификат.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Если вы доверяете сертификату то можно сделать:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Если нет

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/путь/к/сертификату');
```

Так же возможно придётся установить опцию **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**

```
// пример
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
```

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но тут проблема явно в ином. Тем более, что в скрипте я НЕ использую СURL.

После написания этого вопроса я провёл собственные поиски. Причина оказалась в настройке пути к сертификатам.